# syntax error, unexpected IDENTIFIER, expecting '{' or ';' or ':' or '='

Tags: c++, macos

Can someone please help me solve this error 
This is the error:

```
 *** Error in dnabase.h near line 35, column 39:
    syntax error, unexpected IDENTIFIER, expecting '{' or ';' or ':' or '='
    Error parsing file: 'dnabase.h'
```

My operating system is: mac el capitan

The engine I'm using is: Panda3D

This is the code that is the problem: dnbase.h:

```
inline LVecBase4f dgi_extract_color(DatagramIterator& dgi)
{
    double r = dgi.get_uint8() / 255.;
    double g = dgi.get_uint8() / 255.;
    double b = dgi.get_uint8() / 255.;
    double a = dgi.get_uint8() / 255.;
    return LVecBase4f(r, g, b, a);
}
```

something else:

```
The following command return a non-zero value (1): /Developer/Panda3D/bin/interrogate -D__inline -DCPPPARSER -DP3_INTERROGATE=1 -D__cplusplus -fnames -string -refcount -assert -S /Developer/Panda3D/include/parser-inc -S /Developer/Panda3D/include -I /Developer/Panda3D/include -I/Users/mgracer48/Desktop/libpandadna/src/base -I/Users/mgracer48/Desktop/libpandadna/src/suit -I/Users/mgracer48/Desktop/libpandadna/src/components -srcdir /Users/mgracer48/Desktop/libpandadna/src/base -oc /Users/mgracer48/Desktop/libpandadna/src/base_igate.cxx -od /Users/mgracer48/Desktop/libpandadna/src/base.in -python-native -DCPPPARSER -D__STDC__=1 -D__cplusplus -D__inline -longlong __int64 -D_X86_ -DWIN32_VC -DWIN32 -module libpandadna -library base -Dvolatile= config_dna.h dnabase.h DNALoader.h DNAStorage.h
```

Comment: Are you really expecting us to go through all your code and find the problematic line? You should post the whole line in the question.

Comment: Yes. Which line is line 35? I don't intend to count the lines in your question. Please point out the relevant information

Comment: @SergeyA: Assuming the info is correct, this is the `#define DGI_EXTRACT_COLOR dgi_extract_color(dgi)` line. Apparently the error stems from some use of `dgi_extract_color` elsewhere. Maybe it's in a context where `dgi` isn't defined.

Comment: @Mgracer: I can't see any way to determine the problem from what you posted (other than what I've already commented about use of `dgi_extract_color`). You need to reduce the problem to a **minimal but complete example**, and post that.

Comment: @Mgracer You seem to have misunderstood. That's not line 35 and it's not a use of `DGI_EXTRACT_COLOR ` nor `dgi_extract_color`. It's not even clear that the error is coming from a C++ compiler; it doesn't look like something from GCC or Clang. My guess is that this `.h` file is getting fed into the wrong tool.

Comment: That doesn't look like a message from a C++ compiler - I suspect it's from one of Panda's own tools. (Googling the message syntax shows hits for "interrogate".)

Comment: it is line 35 i somehow messed up the src with my changes trying to fix and the original code this is line 35

Comment: should i ask in the engine's forums?

Comment: @Mgracer You can ask here, but please tag it with the correct language. Also, show us the part which you wrote, not the internals of the library.

Comment: what other languages could this be?

Comment: i also didnt write this is an open source project im trying build

Comment: here is the open source project https://github.com/loblao/libpandadna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem i was missing the c++ headers from panda3d engine.